# Change mfn_page_items encoding in wordpress betheme for use offline or in gitlab-ci?

Tags: php, wordpress, gitlab-ci-runner

Why did muffin use encoding?

I should change my wordpress locally offline, then transfer it to the web.

So I convert every domain.com in sql exported to localhost and import it locally.

However `mfn_page_items` (maybe for be-theme) uses encoding. Why? How can I solve this?

My team uses `gitlab-ci!`, so how can I create a `.yml` to do this automatically?